# Determine if any boolean flag is true

Tags: java, performance, oop, optimization, boolean

There is a class that is like a structure for flags. I.e. it is comprised of flags.
E.g.

```
public class Foo { 
  boolean isA;  
  boolean isB;  
  boolean isC;  
  boolean isD;  
  boolean isE;  
  boolean isX;  
  boolean isY;  
}
```

I need to check at some point if at least one of the flags is `true`.
Besides a series of `if` statements e.g.

```
boolean isAnyTrue = false;  
if(foo.isA) isAnyTrue = true; 
else if(foo.isB) isAnyTrue = true;
else if(foo.isC) isAnyTrue = true;
else if(foo.isD) isAnyTrue = true;
else if(foo.isE) isAnyTrue = true;  
else if(foo.isX) isAnyTrue = true;  
else if(foo.isY) isAnyTrue = true;
```

Or

```
boolean isAnyTrue = foo.isA || foo.isB || foo.isC || foo.isD || foo.isE || foo.isX || foo.isY;
```

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Having this many flags is a bit of a dubious design. Could you represent things by an enum, and use an EnumSet instead?

Comment: @AndyTurner: I can't change the code unfortunately (at least not at the moment)

Comment: @AndyTurner: If you want to provide some solution for enumset, that is welcome too although I wont be able to use it for the time being as I can't change that class as mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Add `isAnyTrue()` method to the `Foo` and check all properties:

```java
public boolean isAnyTrue() {
    return isA || isB || ... || isY;
}
```

If the number of properties is too big to handle it in this way, you can use [Reflection](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html) to find all `boolean` properties and check if any is set to `true`.

Comment: Is there also some bitwise alternative that could be more efficient?

Comment: Efficient in what terms? Do you have a reason to think that oring all the flags together is a performance problem for your application?

Comment: @tgdavies: no, strictly speaking I think you are right. It is more of a learning in case it is useful than thinking that the alternative would be much more performant. btw oring wouldn't work I think

Comment: @Jim, we have only two options: check all the properties explicite using `||` operator or use Reflection. Take a look on the @Sanjeet Jagdev answer. It is not totally bad idea to have set of boolean properties in configuration `POJO`. Every solution has it drawbacks. If this method will be used a lot implement it explicite. If this method will be used only once for a while you can use Reflection and will not notice any performance issue.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I think this is a bad way to do things. But none the less since you mentioned that you can't change the code as of now. Maybe you could look into Reflection, which again isn't the most optimized way to do it.

```
public boolean isTruePresent() throws IllegalAccessException {
    var fields = Foo.class.getDeclaredFields();
    Foo test = new Foo();
    boolean hasTrue = false;

    for(var field : fields) {
        if(field.getType().getSimpleName().equals("boolean")) {
            hasTrue = hasTrue || (boolean) field.get(test);
        }
    }
    return hasTrue;
}
```

Comment: If any of the property is true, method should return `true`. You do not need to scan all properties. So, you can improve your method by returning `true` if condition in for-each loop is met. At the end `return false`. You do not need to `hasTrue` variable.

Comment: Regardless of the performance impact, you should use `field.getType() == boolean.class` instead of comparing names. Further, you can use `field.getBoolean(test)` instead of getting an `Object` and casting it to `boolean`. The entire code can be simplified to `Foo test = new Foo(); for(var field : Foo.class.getDeclaredFields()) { if(field.getType() == boolean.class && field.getBoolean(test); return true; } return false;`